# WHY its not scrolling x-axis with overflow-x scroll.Instead it scroll to y-axis

Tags: html, css

**Not scrolling x-axis with overflow-x scroll. Instead it scroll to y-axis.**

This code snippet:

```css
        .col {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        background-color: #3e5771;
        width: 90%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 2px solid #1abc9c;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    
    .box img {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 8px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col">
    <div class="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-g-200-400-10.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-g-200-400-10.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-g-200-400-10.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-g-200-400-10.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-g-200-400-10.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-g-200-400-10.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain your issue and make a snippet so that we can test it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to make a horizontal scrolling and prevent vertical scrolling.

You did set the `overflow-x : auto` alright, but you forgot to set `overflow-y : hidden`. Also, to force the content on one row, one easy way is to use `display:flex` :

```css
.col {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: #3e5771;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid #1abc9c;
  border-radius: 15px;
  
  overflow-y: hidden; /* add this */
}

.box{
 display : flex; /* add this */
}

.box img {
   /* display: inline-block; Remove this */
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, just asking , if you use `overflow-x : auto` in this case is it neccasary adding `overflow-y: hidden;` ? i know you added `overflow-x: scroll;` , just asking for future ref...

Comment: If the content doesn't overflow the container, then `overflow-y:hidden` is indeed unnecessary. `I know you added 'overflow-x: scroll;'` Uh, no, I didn't

Comment: wait im not being saracastic was a simple question, and look at your snippet, i see `.col {
  overflow-x: scroll;}` ?? there is nothing wrong dude, uhhhhhh ????

Comment: I know you're not being sarcastic. I didn't add `overflow-x: scroll`. It is part of OP's original code. Check the question.

Comment: yess sorry should have said `i know you used OP's` - `overflow-x: scroll`